# How do I keep a progress bar going?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a progress bar after loading a picture that is indeterminate and runs until the detect function is finished. I tried this code but the progress bar stays still until after the detect function is done running, it then moves back and forth. How do I make it so that it starts moving before the detect function runs, and continues running while the detect function is running?

```py
def progress(): 
    pb = ttk.Progressbar(
        root,
        orient='horizontal',
        mode='indeterminate',
        length=280,
    )
    pb.pack(padx = 20, pady = 10)
    pb.start()


def selecting():
    global displaynumber
    global f1
    panel.configure(image='')
    root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="/",
        title="Select file",
        filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    f1 = root.filename
    displaynumber = 2
    # img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=f1)
    # label = tk.Label(root, image=img, width = 200, height = 200) 
    #print (root.filename)
    progress()
    detect(f1)


tk.Radiobutton(
    root, 
    text="Select Image from file",
    padx=20, 
    variable=v,
    command=selecting, 
    value=1,
    font=("Courier", 25),
    bg="#FFFFFF").pack(anchor=tk.W)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: It sounds like you need to use threading.